# Make report title equal to last field in table Access 2013?

Tags: ms-access-2013, ms-access-2016

I have a report that displays information from a query of a Trucks Table in access. I also have another table called Versions that stores the date of the last edit. In the title of the report I currently have the following control source.

```
="Trucks Shipped To " & ([Forms]![Customer Specific Trucks Query]![CityCombo]) & ", " & ([Forms]![Customer Specific Trucks Query]![StateCombo])
```

I would like to add to the end of the title through last edit date ie
"Trucks shipped to City state through 3/23/2016"

I don't know how to pull the last edit date into the title. I imagine it will start like this.

```
="Trucks Shipped To " & ([Forms]![Customer Specific Trucks Query]![CityCombo]) & ", " & ([Forms]![Customer Specific Trucks Query]![StateCombo]) & ([Versions]![Last Edit])
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by making my query that the report is binded to also pull data from my versions table. I then simply added & [LastEdit] to my title.